# How to print into python tkinter entry field by pressing a button?

Tags: python, tkinter

So, i'm trying to create a program that creates a random number (using randint) to an entry field, when a button is pressed. But I can't figure out how to do it.

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import Entry, END, E
from random import randint

root = tkinter.Tk()
root.title('Number Generator')

e = Entry(root, font=("LEMON MILK Bold", 24), width=15, borderwidth=10)
e.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3, padx=50, pady=50)
e.delete(0, END)
e.insert(0, number)

number=print(randint(0, 100))

#Definitions

def button_generate():
    print(number)

#Buttons

button_generate = tkinter.Button(root, text="Random number", font=("LEMON MILK Bold", 24), padx=10, 
pady=10, command=button_generate)
button_exit = tkinter.Button(root, text="Exit", font=("LEMON MILK Bold", 14), padx=5, pady=5, 
command=root.quit)

#Grid

button_generate.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=3)
button_exit.grid(row=2, column=2, sticky=E)

root.mainloop()
```

So basically how can I make the random number print into the entry field? (Right now it is not printing anywhere due to my bad code)

Comment: You should call `randint()` inside `button_generate()` and insert the result into entry `e`.  BTW you named both a function and a button the same name `button_generate`, rename one of them to other name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this out

```
from tkinter import *
from random import randint


def set_text():
    number=randint(0, 100)
    e.delete(0,END)
    e.insert(0,number)
    print(number)

win = Tk()

e = Entry(win,width=10)
e.pack()

b1 = Button(win,text="Gen",command=set_text)
b1.pack()
win.mainloop()
```

Comment: Appologies.. Didnt see your comment that you got it working

Comment: The `lambda` is not necessary.  Just `command=set_text`.

Answer (score 0):

I like Karthik's solution! It's straight to the point.
It suited half my needs, but not 100% because I wanted to copy the text from 'e' to my clipboard (after pressing a different button). Thanks to Karthik, I was able to accomplish this by doing the following:

```
from tkinter import *
from random import randint
import pyperclip as pc

def get_text():
    number = e.get()
    if len(e.get()) != 0:
        pc.copy(number)
        print(f"Number is: '{number}'\nIt is now copied to your clipboard!")
    else:
        print("There's nothing to copy!")

def set_text():
    number = randint(0, 100)
    e.delete(0, END)
    e.insert(0, number)
    print(number)

win = Tk()

e = Entry(win, width = 10)
e.pack()

b1 = Button(win, text = "Gen", command = set_text)
b1.pack()

b2 = Button(win, text = "Get", command = get_text)
b2.pack()

win.mainloop()
```

Please note that I am using a 3rd party module for the *copy* functionality.